# Literature on potential games

Tags: reference-request, game-theory

Is there any comprehensive survey on potential games and their usage in game theory?

Potential games seminal paper is by [Monderer and Shapley](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~mansour/sem-game-02-03/monderer-potential-96.pdf).

I could find [this chapter of a book online](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwi1nLeKq_HQAhXJA8AKHVl-DzIQFggyMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783319308678-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1566179-p179884998&usg=AFQjCNHXyLKOE48oCVPs9NKHo7reGy14jA&sig2=GQyMTzcY6WetSC9zgJklBg&cad=rja), but I am not sure from which book it is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Your link contains chapter 2 of the following book:

Potential Game Theory - Applications in Radio Resource Allocation

Authors: Quang Duy Lã, Yong Huat Chew, Boon-Hee Soong 
ISBN: 978-3-319-30867-8 (Print) 978-3-319-30869-2 (Online)

Perhaps Jason R. Marden * , Jeff S. Shamma , "Game Theory and Distributed Control", Chapter 16 in "Handbook of game theory", Volume 4, 2015 could helpful as well.